# Php rewrite url through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii, zurmocrm

I want to rewrite some url by using ***.htaccess*** rewrite

I have url something like this:

### domain.com/app/index.php/appmedia/default/login

and want to rewrite users to

### domain.com/app/index.php/zurmo/default/login

So, what will happen is users will see appmedia in browser but in the backend it will access zurmo

I'm new to php and have read some blogs like [this](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs) have no luck

Also, have tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/index.php/appmedia/default/login.*$ http://domain.com/app/index.php/zurmo/default/login [R=301,L]
```

---

it says The page isn't redirecting properly

### Edit of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/index.php/appmedia/default/login.*$ http://mydomainx.com/app/index.php/zurmo/default/login [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is `/app/` a real directory?

Comment: @anubhava yes, its codeignitor I think and when I inspect browser...for ex, domain.com then its showing navigated to domain.com/app..../login

Comment: Ok then can you provide .htaccess which is in `/app/` (if any)

Comment: @anubhava there isn't any .htaccess inside it.

Comment: ok then show content of `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: @anubhava there isn't any contents before then I edited it and put which I have updated in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73761/discussion-between-just-code-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `[R=301]` and expect the URL not to change. R means redirect. So it will change to the URL you told it to. For an internal rewrite you need to leave that off.

If you have .htaccess in your document root then you should be able to do this. I don't know how your setup is but this should rewrite the URI.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/index.php/appmedia/default/login/?$ /app/index.php/zurmo/default/login [L]
```

If you are using ***yii framework*** do like this:

```
'urlManager' => array (
 'class' => 'application.core.components.ZurmoUrlManager',
 'urlFormat' => 'path',
'caseSensitive' => true,
'showScriptName' => true,
'rules' => array(
 // Begin Not Coding Standard
 // API REST patterns
 array('zurmo/default/login','pattern' => 'appmedia/default/login',
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply got this error after applying that `Unable to resolve the request "appmedia/default/login".`

Comment: I'm assuming appmedia is not a real directory. Try my updated code.